# when to use java scriplets and when to avoid?

Tags: java, jsp

I google about the java scriplet and found that scriplets in java is not a good practice , but we need them for the sake of easiness sometimes, so my question is about the appropriate usage of scriplet and when to avoid them?

Comment: [check here] (www.coderanch.com/t/466754/JSP/java/EL-good-scriptlets-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, you may eliminate usage of scriplets in any case with usage of EL and JSTL.

1. It is difficult to properly format.
2. EL looks better :) and you can use it in Velocity, Thymeleaf, Spring and so on.
3. JSTL is a set of extra html tags + EL.

Answer (score 1):

I would say its only ever appropriate to use scriptlets when tag libraries do not provide equivalent functionality (which isn't often).

Also, JSP scriptlets should not be used for writing business logic. Rather, JSP scriptlets are used if necessary to transform data (also called "value objects") returned from processing the client's requests into a proper client-ready format. Even then, this would be better done with a front controller servlet or a custom tag.

http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2010/07/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.html